# Avoid my sons inheriting counties?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

In my current game my first son had very bad traits so I do not want to play with him once "I" die. My 2nd son has very good traits and he would be perfectly suitable to follow in my footsteps.

However I am not ruling long enough to change succession laws. I also believe that sending him to church was considered an exploit and has been removed. Since there is a strong plot on my assassination I decided to come out of hiding and imprison my son. I read that banishing would do the trick and I had very good standings with my vassals so I tried that but it did not work. Strangely after a couple of days he arrived at my court again so I executed him after taking another huge hit for imprisoning him again. Now I am waiting to die or be assassinated.

Was this really the only option I had? It seems much more realistic to send my son to a church or deny him any claims then messing up my whole reputation like this.

Comment: Regarding giving your son a bishophoric so they don't inherit: It still works with secondary heirs in gravelkind succession to concentrate the inheritance at the primary heir, but you can no longer disinherit your primary heir that way.

Comment: "The sooner you start working on the untimely death of your heir, the better." - It's a wonderful world.